# Allocating memory with new in the DLL - how to release?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, memory, dll

I have many export functions in a DLL that output pointers, and they allocate memory in those functions. For example:

```cpp
DLL_EXPORT void some_function(const char*** param)
{
    *param= new const char*[somenumber];
    //someting
    //in some for-cycle
    char* somestr = new char[somenumber1];
    strcpy(somestr , somelocalstr);
    //someting
}
```

it's used in other projects like this (I won't write `LoadLibrary()`, `GetProcAddress()` here, it's already done):

```
void some_function_that_uses_dll()
{
    const char** param;
    some_function(&param); 
    //something
    //some for-cycle
    const char* somestring = param[i];
    //something
    non_local_std_string = somestring;
}
```

It's how I received the project.

It seems that obvious memory leaks are happening here. But when I tried to write `delete[] somestring;` after the `non_local_std_string = somestring;`, I've got a crash. Probably because it is different projects.

Is there a way to free those memory that have been allocated in the DLL, after it would have been copied into the `std::string` (`non_local_std_string`)? Or, does `std::string` move those memory?

Comment: export a function from your dll which calls delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `std::string` will not take ownership of the allocated memory.  The user of your DLL is responsible for freeing the memory after done using it, such as copying it into `std::string`.

In this case, you must either:

1. export an additional function that the user of the DLL must call to `delete[]` the arrays when it is done using them, eg:

```cpp
DLL_EXPORT int some_function(char*** param)
{
    *param = nullptr;
    int res = 0;

    try
    {
        *param = new char*[somenumber];
        for(int i = 0; i < somenumber; ++i)
        {
            ...
            char* somestr = new char[somenumber1];
            strcpy(somestr, somelocalstr);
            (*param)[res] = somestr;
            ++res;
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < res; ++i) {
            delete[] (*param)[i];
        }
        delete[] *param;
        return -1;
    }

    return res;
}

DLL_EXPORT void free_function(char** param, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        delete[] param[i];
    }
    delete[] param;
}
```

```cpp
void some_function_that_uses_dll()
{
    char** param;
    int n = some_function(&param); 

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        char* somestring = param[i];
        //...
    }

    free_function(param, n);
}
```

2. allocate and free the arrays using OS-provided memory management functions, not `new[]`/`delete[]`. This way, the user of the DLL can simply call the OS functions directly, eg:

```cpp
DLL_EXPORT int some_function(char*** param)
{
    *param = (char**) LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, sizeof(char*) * somenumber);
    if (*param == NULL) return -1;

    int res = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < somenumber; ++i)
    {
        ...
        char* somestr = (char*) LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, sizeof(char) * somenumber1);
        if (somestr == NULL)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < res; ++j) {
                LocalFree((*param)[j]);
            }
            LocalFree(*param);
            return -1;
        }
        
        strcpy(somestr, somelocalstr);
        (*param)[res] = somestr;
        ++res;
    }

    return res;
}
```

```cpp
void some_function_that_uses_dll()
{
    const char** param;
    int n = some_function(&param); 

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        char* somestring = param[i];
        //...
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        LocalFree(param[i]);
    }
    LocalFree(param);
}
```